# How to add conditional to filter?

Tags: angularjs

I need to turn on/off filter in my dir-paginate section

I tried to get `$scope` variable from controller to my .filter but I have troubles to achieve it..

```
<tr dir-paginate="item in items | lastEntry:queryFrom:queryTo">
```

```
.filter('lastEntry', function() {
    return function(data, greaterThan, lowerThan) {
        data=data.filter(function(item){
            return item.lastEntry > greaterThan $$ item.lastEntry < lowerThan;
        });
        return data;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally your code looks fine, however I think you have a syntax error.

If you're looking for an and condition then `$$` should be `&&`:

```
return item.lastEntry > greaterThan && item.lastEntry < lowerThan;
```

I wrote an article a few years back with a working example of conditional filters with AngularJs which you may find useful:

https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/angularjs/filtering-arrays-in-angularjs/

Comment: yes, there should be &&... :) I will check your link